# PHP- Unable to insert data in Online Website but successfully adding the data in Xampp for same site

Tags: php

Actually i have three forms which are being used to store data into Database. They all are working fine on Xampp server but when i have migrated that website on Online Server .... One form is adding data successfully and others two are deleting and editing successfully but i am unable to add the new record into them.
I am unable to understand that .what is going through ..code is fine , cuz it is working fine on xampp server and with same code , one form is working fine .
So , what is going through i don't know ...

I have changed the layout of code and tried checking out the insert queries but they are also fine.

```
<?php   
require_once 'core.php';

$valid['success'] = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

if($_POST) {

    $productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $Rate = $_POST['rate']; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name,rate,active) 
    VALUES ('$productName','$Rate', 1)";

    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $valid['success'] = true;
        $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Added";  
    } else {
        $valid['success'] = false;
        $valid['messages'] = "Error while adding the Category";
    }

    $connect->close();

    echo json_encode($valid);

} // /if $_POST
```

Comment: 1) you're open to SQL injection. 2) Anyone can set a post request, so you're if statement doesn't really catch much (in my eyes)

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, i will take care of SQP injection ... thnks for pointing out ...But for now, can u please figure out why data is not being inserted?
Cuz the same code is inserting the data for another form ?

Comment: enable errors - then let the server tel lyou

Comment: it's showing NO error ..Dear

Comment: You say this has been migrated to your Online Site. It's already TOO LATE for your [SQL Injection Attack Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). They need fixing NOW before you move any more code to the LIVE server

Comment: **If this is a LIVE Server it will be configured to NOT SHOW ERRORS** Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @Sham did you check logs? did you enable the server to show errors? do you have xdebug?

Comment: Can you please check this out? if I'll send u website name and credentials?

Comment: Out of interest, where do you make a connection to your database?

Comment: in db_connection file, which is included in core.php as shown above ...

Comment: @treyBake yes i have enabled it and it has shown previous errors ,but it is showing no Error now ...

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home/classic2/public_html/functions.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/classic2/public_html/product.php:1) in /home/classic2/public_html/home.php on line 6

Comment: and there's your error^

Comment: nah ,i have rectified it

Comment: but m still unable to enter Data ? Can u please check this out ,i mean by entering data ,hope you would get to know that what is real wrong ?